# What is the most cost effective way for an individual to contribute to global climate action? (For an Australian resident)

Tags: climate-change

**Edited: I would like to spend *money* in the most effective ways (local tax considerations included)**

I understand that in order to be effective at tackling climate change there needs to be action at a level of global emissions. That isn't to discount the importance of individual concessions. But for the sake of this question, let's assume I have taken all reasonable steps to minimize my personal carbon footprint. To the point that any additional reduction requires non-trivial investments of time / money.

I would like to know what are the most cost effective ways of spending *money* to reduce emissions. Not large amounts by any means, but enough that I would prefer not to be throwing it away without thinking about how far it will actually go.

At the moment it seams to me that investing the money in [*the founders pledge* climate fund](https://founderspledge.com/funds/climate-change-fund) would be the most effective. Although I am located in Australia, and so would be unable to get any tax benefit from that. Is there a more tax effective equivalent for Australian tax residents?

Comment: The most cost effective way is to reduce your own contribution - and you probably even gain money by doing so. Use your car less, reduce your energy consumption, eat less meat, buy less stuff and/or more sustainable stuff, etc, pp.

Comment: Is it though? I mean the car is a mute point for me, and I'm not by any means an excessive consumer in other domains, but it isn't clear that these actions make any measurable impact on *global* emissions

Comment: At least the authors of the fouders pledge [climate & lifestyle report](https://founderspledge.com/stories/climate-and-lifestyle-report) would argue that putting $1000 in their fund dwarves any other action you might take, other than maybe not having a child. (See figure 7 in link)

Comment: You are asking about cost efficiency, not about absolute impact. So yes, your own behaviour is the most cost efficient way to reduce emissions, since it cuts your own expenses without having to invest any money. And unless you're handicapped or need to transport stuff for your job, reducing car travels isn't a mute point. So don't try to buy yourself a clean consiousness, rather act on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Or you don't own a car. I guess my point is reductions only take you so far. As far as I can see I am already living a relatively minimal lifestyle, as far as things within my control are concerned, and as far as I have the time / capacity to know. But I still have money I could spend to do more. So how *should* I spend it?

Comment: Should I reword the question? What I want is most bang per buck. Where bang is emissions reductions.

Comment: It might actually come from a different corner then you'd expect: could very well be that the most effective way which mainly costs time (if you want you can fill in AUD/hour) is persuading enough other people or entities (governments, ...) to do something for the climate. A bit too many possibilities to sum up though, so just one simple example: suppose you live in a town where road lights are on the entire night and you can get them to turn them off lights at night instead for the future that's not unlikely going to save more than anything else you can personally do over a lifetime.

Comment: I would edit a bit to address some of the things in the comments -- you're assuming you've already done everything feasible to reduce your personal emissions, and you're looking to invest or donate money to further reduce emissions. So you're specifically looking for an organization to donate to, or a fund to invest in, which will reduce your tax liability in Australia.

Comment: Thanks @LShaver, I have clarified my intent and think the question is better for it. You are right, I am looking for an organization (or rather I think I have found one in founders-pledge-fund, and want to know if I can do better).